# Solve for x in $\tan x=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to solve for $x$ for $\tan x=2x$?

My cousin asked me about this and I wondering if there was some sort of trig identity I had to know.

Comment: By inspection, $x = 0$ is a solution. There are infinitely many more, one for each period of $\tan$, but they [don't look nice](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x%29+%3D+2x). I strongly doubt they are nice in any way. Asymptotically, they'll be close to the asymptotes of $\tan$.

Comment: Closing as a possible duplicate, when the purported duplicate has only one non-answer with zero upvotes, seems unhelpful to me.  I vote against closing this question.

Comment: This is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). Other than $x=0$, the other values cannot be expressed or determined analytically.